# How can I keep my persimmon tree warm?

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, plant-care, temperature

I'm trying to grow my persimmon tree, but my country has a very cold weather in winter and a few months with above freezing daytime temperature in summer (USDA hardiness zone from 2 to 4), so I am growing this seedling indoors. What can I do to keep it alive?

[image]

Comment: Need some more information. Where exactly are you and what kind of persimmons do you have? Some persimmons can withstand decently cold winters into USDA zone 4

Comment: Is a heat mat a consideration? 14° F. is pretty cold for indoors. Is it that cold where you are, or just where the tree is? What are your hopes for the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week it is growing well at -10°C (14°F). I don't know its soil temperature, but I am using the following method to keep it warm:

1. During night I am covering it with plastic bag and blanket.

[image]

2. During daytime I am trying to let it get more sunlight by using metallic kitchen paper.

[image]

**Editor's note:** I believe the temperature indoor might be indeed -10°C (14°F) because outside it's usually -30 to -40°C (-22 to -40°F).